# How to create a custom title window in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, window, title, borderless

it is my first question.
I download a game named BlackWhite from Mac App Store.
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blackwhite/id420650954?mt=12
I'd like to know how to crete a window with a custom title like the app. Is it a borderless window? but it has window buttons...

Answer (score 4):

> I'd like to know how to create a window
>   with a custom title like the app.

**Bold NSWindow Title**

```
- titleFont
{
    return [NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
}

- (NSRect)_titlebarTitleRect
{
    return NSOffsetRect([super _titlebarTitleRect], 0, -1);
}
```

Link:
http://andymatuschak.org/articles/2006/01/11/making-the-hud-item-1-a-frame-themed-party

**Additional NSWindow customization**
*(like the example you provided)*

TunesWindow by Matt Gemmell (using background images):
- http://mattgemmell.com/source/ 
Custom NSWindow by Matt Gallagher:
- http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html 
DarkWindow by Rafaël Warnault:
- http://www.read-write.fr/blog/?p=32
NSThemeFrame usage:
 
- http://parmanoir.com/Custom_NSThemeFrame

Comment: The second link is from Matt Gallagher, not Gemmell.

Comment: Thank, Anne.
I have read all example from your answer. most of them used private API. But a app used private API will be rejected from App Store.
Now, I can use the way form http://mattgemmell.com/source/ to create a custom background color window, But can not change title font without private API.